How to handle rpm dependencies when nothing provides dependencies?
I have a legacy software package currently distributed by zip files and want to turn these zip files into an rpm. During the rpmbuild process, I unzip the files and specify the files/directories for installation and a few small config steps. Easy peasy. The problem is, rpmbuild automagically scans files in the packages and determines required dependencies. Not sure exactly how these dependencies are extrapolated but so it goes. When I try to install the package, dnf/yum throws errors nothing provides some identified dependencies.
Case in point: somehow, someway /bin/perl is named as a dependency:
$ sudo dnf install mypackage.el8.x86_64.rpm
Updating Subscription Management repositories.
Last metadata expiration check: 1:17:40 ago on Fri 26 Apr 2024 10:59:11 AM EDT.
Error: 
 Problem: conflicting requests
  - nothing provides /bin/perl needed by mypackage.el8.x86_64 from @commandline

There aren't any packages which provide /bin/perl. All perl packages install /usr/bin/perl and /bin is a symlink to /usr/bin. perl is only one of a long list of automagically identified dependencies. It seems like I need a way to either tell rpmbuild to skip dependency scanning or skip dependency resolution upon installation.
